# AngularJS select dropdown not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

I have problem with the select tag, which got populated with some data from a WCF-Service. When I click on the selectbox it won`t open (see picture below), but when i navigate with the keyboard arrows, i can select my data. The other sad thing is: it does not happen regular. Sometimes it occours, sometimes not.

This happens after I click on the select box:

[image: Select box]

To this point of time the data is already loaded from the service.

The concept of the two select boxes shown below: After selecting something in the first select box (*name="kind"*), the second should appear. This works perfectly fine, even when the error occurs and I can only select the data with the keyboard. But if the bug is in the first select box, it is also in the second.

**Setup:**
IE 11, AngularJS v1.5.5, Bootstrap v3.3.5 did not happen in FF or Chrome

**Datastructure of *$agronomicservice.kindsoftasks.kindsoftasks***

- It is a list of Objects
- Object: *[{Id: 1, Name: "somename"}, {Id: 2, Name: "somename2"}]*

**HTML-Code**

```
<table class="tablePadding">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="taskagronomicsFontSize">{{i18n.sometranslation1}}:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="kind"
                    ng-options="label.Id as label.Name for label in $agronomicservice.kindsoftasks.kindsoftasks"
                    ng-model="$taskservice.currentTask.kindoftask"
                    ng-change="setKindOfTaskinPath()"
                    ng-disabled="isExistingTask || taskFinished"
                    class="form-control"
                    style="width: 200px;">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-hide="$taskservice.currentTask.kindoftask == null">
            <td ng-hide="$taskservice.currentTask.kindoftask == enums.KINDOFTASK.pp" class="taskagronomicsFontSize">{{i18n.sometranslation2}}:</td>
            <td ng-show="$taskservice.currentTask.kindoftask == enums.KINDOFTASK.pp" class="taskagronomicsFontSize">{{i18n.sometranslation3}}:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="application"
                    ng-options="option.Id as option.Name for option in $agronomicservice.applications.applications | acApplicationFilter:$taskservice.currentTask.kindoftask"
                    ng-model="$taskservice.currentTask.application"
                    ng-change="setApplicationinPath()"
                    ng-disabled="isExistingTask || taskFinished"
                    class="form-control"
                    style="width: 200px;">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </body>
 </table>
```

**Extract of JS-Code**

```
var promiseKOT = $scope.$taskservice.updateKindsoftasks();
promiseKOT.then(
   function(newKindsoftasks) {
       $scope.$agronomicservice.kindsoftasks = newKindsoftasks;
   });

var updateKindsoftasks = function(){
    var promise = $http.post(__serverURL__+'/GetData?' + new Date().getTime(),
        4,
        {
            headers : {
                'SessionHash': __SessionHash__,
                'Access-Control-Request-Methods': 'GET, POST',
            },
            timeout : 600000,
            cache : false,
            responseType : 'json'
        }
    )
    .then(function(response) {
        return {kindsoftasks: response.data};
    },
    function(errorPayload) {
       //Some error handling
    });

    return promise;
};
```

**CSS**

```
.form-control {
   font-size: 14px;
   border-radius: 0px;
   font-family: Verdana;
}

.form-control:hover {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none !important;
}

.tablePadding > tbody > tr > td {
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-left: 1px;
   padding-right: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.tablePadding > thead > tr > th {
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-left: 1px;
   padding-right: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you exposing all service "$taskservice" and "$agronomicservice" to the scope? In the scope creates 2 variables, one array of objects for the first select and another to the second select. uses those variables in "ng-options". if you want i can answer the question with some code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer fabiosilvalima. The "$taskservice" is about the connection to the wcf-service and the datahandling, which arrives in the client. The "$agronomicservice" is about some agronic logic, which is used in the modul. I would appreciate a code based reply from You, but the general problem is not the data inside the select box. The data is available all the time even when the bug occurs. I think it is more some kind of display problem.

Comment: can you do this in a ngInit?

console.log($agronomicservice.kindsoftasks.kindsoftasks)

Use google chrom F12 to read it

so far it seems that the used array is empty, I could be wrong.

Comment: As i said, the data is available, because i can navigate through the dropdown with the keyboard arrows and also see my data. A console log confirmed this. The thing is, that the dropdown is not showing when there is the expected data.